# I can't ask questions using Tor on tor.stackexchange.com

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, censorship

I use Tor Browser 7.5.2 on Windows 7 and apparently I can't post question on tor.stackexchange.com (this website), I usually always post question on stackexchange using Tor but this time I can't (see my screenshot bellow).

The issues is huge guys, if even Tor techies people can't figure out what wrong with that

For my part I'm not going ask all questions I'm willing to if Tor is blocked on this website this look like "censorship in upstream"

[image: Tor traffic censored]

"QUANTUM to degrade/deny/disrupt Tor access? "

- ref : https://www.eff.org/files/2014/04/09/20131004-guard-tor_stinks.pdf

Thank you for understanding. :)

Comment: If It don't belong there can you not close this question but move it where it belong ? Thank you. :)

Comment: quantum is totally unrelated to this. picking random words out of snowden documents is just silly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tor and it says abuse is originating from "your" network, it means the network of the exit node. Not your real network.

To fix this, select the Tor browser button and select New identity or New Tor circuit for this site. If it still does not work, close Tor browser and open it again.

Repeat until the message is gone. I find that it is easier to make a dedicated Tor Stackexchange account and log in before posting a question.

This sort of denial of service is caused by spammers who posts their spam on this site proxying through Tor.

Comment: Yes I tried that multiple before giving up, can you use captcha and not google captcha please?

Comment: Then go to https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#advanced and search for an exit node (lower speed ones usually have less "abuse"). Then add `exitnodes {address}` to your `torrc` file and restart Tor Browser. Remember to revert `torrc` file after.

Answer (score 0):

Exit node is just one part of the problem here, the other part is that Tor.StackExchange does not have a Tor hidden service entrance for it, lol :) Even a Facebook has it - you should write an email to the support team to ask them to do so. A lot of abuse comes from Tor and Anonymous Proxies, sadly - so this red-flagging became an ubiquitous behavior nowdays, sadly...